# g.list problem in GRASS command line

Tags: grass-gis, windows-8, command-line, grass.script

I am using GRASS 6.4.3 (installed with osGeo4w), and I have this question：

As I type `g.list`, a function window will pop out, and all functions and results are fine. But when I type `g.list rast`, I got this message：

> '%GRASS_PAGER%'  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The photo below, left one is the correct output in popout window as I type in command `g.list`, and the right one is the message I got in command line as I type in `g.list rast`：
[image]

But I have already add the following paths in my path environment variables：

```
1. C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin
2. C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
```

How can I solve this problem? I am using GRASS 6.4.3 under windows 8.1 64-bits, please give me any suggestion!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. Please add a comment to my answer with a short description how you finally solve the problem!

Comment: @StefanB. thank you and I will try to look at references you gave me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the following:

```
g.list type=rast
```

or

```
g.list type=vect
```

Besides you can use `g.mlist type=rast` for (I think) a better look on your raster/vector files.

**Update**

Maybe there is a problem with your installation. Take a look at this [manual](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/CompileOnWindows) for compiling grass under windows (look for the msys-grass) and further information [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-grass).

Additionally you can try to use grass in [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

Comment: I have tried g.list type=rast and g.list type=vect and got the same result, but as I tried g.mlist the results were fine. Why can't I use g.list command?